# Javascript - Filter geojson based on other json's values

Tags: javascript, json, filter, geojson

I am struggling with filtering a geojson based on the values of another JSON. Specifically, Iam trying to filter the geojson based on the id's in the other json. Every time, my filtered geojson returns null.

I have created a JSfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/liostse/ph9qfav0/23/) showing what I am trying to do.

The code is

```
    mygeojson={crs: {properties: {name: "EPSG:4326"}, type: "name"},
features: [
    {geometry: {coordinates: [25, 37], type: "Point"},properties: {"wineryid":3},type:"Feature"},
  {geometry: {coordinates: [26, 37], type: "Point"},properties: {"wineryid":45},type:"Feature"},
  {geometry: {coordinates: [25, 38], type: "Point"},properties: {"wineryid":34},type:"Feature"},
  {geometry: {coordinates: [28, 37], type: "Point"},properties: {"wineryid":42},type:"Feature"},
  {geometry: {coordinates: [25, 342], type: "Point"},properties: {"wineryid":80},type:"Feature"},
  {geometry: {coordinates: [25.24, 37.12], type: "Point"},properties: {"wineryid":120},type:"Feature"}], type:"FeatureCollection"};
mylist=[{id:1, name:"test1"},{id:34,name:"test2"}];
tempgeojson = mygeojson.features.filter(function (item) {
  return (mylist.every(f => item.properties.id === f.id) )
});
filteredgeojson={};
filteredgeojson.features=tempgeojson;
filteredgeojson.crs=mygeojson.crs;
filteredgeojson.type="FeatureCollection";
```

How can I get the filtered geojson I need? (In this example, the expected geojson is about id's 1 and 34.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code for features filtering

```
filteredgeojson.features = mygeojson.features.filter(item => { 
     if(mylist.filter(myitem => myitem.id === item.properties.wineryid).length > 0) { 
          return item;
      }
});
```

Comment: Great answer! Simple, short and it works fast. Accepted and thanks!